# What's the initial stack layout in ELF on x86_32 Linux?

Tags: linux, stack, elf

I started a 32-bit process with a minimal argv and envp and made a hexdump starting at esp and ending at 0xffffe000, and got this:

```
00000000: 0100 0000 7adf ffff 0000 0000 a8df ffff  ....z...........
00000010: c2df ffff 0000 0000 2000 0000 80cc fff7  ........ .......
00000020: 2100 0000 00c0 fff7 1000 0000 fffb ab0f  !...............
00000030: 0600 0000 0010 0000 1100 0000 6400 0000  ............d...
00000040: 0300 0000 3480 0408 0400 0000 2000 0000  ....4....... ...
00000050: 0500 0000 0600 0000 0700 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0800 0000 0000 0000 0900 0000 6f88 0408  ............o...
00000070: 0b00 0000 e803 0000 0c00 0000 e803 0000  ................
00000080: 0d00 0000 e803 0000 0e00 0000 e803 0000  ................
00000090: 1700 0000 0000 0000 1900 0000 5bdf ffff  ............[...
000000a0: 1f00 0000 cadf ffff 0f00 0000 6bdf ffff  ............k...
000000b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0039 9456 fb71  ...........9.V.q
000000c0: 5e17 6993 cf5f 001c 893a 4469 3638 3600  ^.i.._...:Di686.
000000d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 2f68 6f6d 652f  ........../home/
000000e0: 7462 6f64 742f 6973 682f 6275 696c 642f  tbodt/ish/build/
000000f0: 7465 7374 732f 6865 6c6c 6f2d 636c 6962  tests/hello-clib
00000100: 2d73 7461 7469 6300 5057 443d 2f68 6f6d  -static.PWD=/hom
00000110: 652f 7462 6f64 742f 6973 682f 6275 696c  e/tbodt/ish/buil
00000120: 6400 5348 4c56 4c3d 3000 2f68 6f6d 652f  d.SHLVL=0./home/
00000130: 7462 6f64 742f 6973 682f 6275 696c 642f  tbodt/ish/build/
00000140: 7465 7374 732f 6865 6c6c 6f2d 636c 6962  tests/hello-clib
00000150: 2d73 7461 7469 6300 0000 0000 0000 0000  -static.........
```

The first few things in that I can identify as `argc`, `argv[0]`, `argv[1]` (which is just `NULL`), `envp[0]`, `envp[1]`, and `envp[2]` (also just `NULL`), and at the end I can see the strings that argv and envp are pointing to. What's all the rest of the stuff? (from 0x18 to 0xd9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's all the rest of the stuff?

The `AUX` vector. The kernel uses this to pass various information on startup that's useful to the dynamic linker and the C library. Details [here](http://articles.manugarg.com/aboutelfauxiliaryvectors). For an up-to-date list of components of the auxiliary vector, see [the `getauxval` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getauxval.3.html).

Comment: It does seem like that's most of the stuff, but the AUX vector ends at 0xb8, and after 16 bytes of padding there's 0x10 bytes unaccounted for

Comment: @tbodt The `"i686"` at `0xcc` is likely where the `AT_PLATFORM` points to.

Comment: I don't see `AT_PLATFORM` in the list you linked?

Comment: @tbodt The blog post is dated. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getauxval.3.html